# Could not get PostgreSQL 11.2 to start. Tried deleting everything, and now PostgreSQL 11.2 Refuses to install with an error

Tags: windows, postgresql

I tried installing PostgreSQL 11.2 on Windows through this link: https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/postgresql/installers.jsp/

but the program would not start no matter what I tried. A quick black window would appear for a tenth of a second, disappear, and then absolutely nothing would happen.

Thus, I uninstalled it and deleted the directory and tried to install PostgreSQL 11.2 on Windows through this link:
https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

It installed properly, but when I opened my file explorer to C: where the directory should have been installed I was given an error "PostgreSQL could not be found". I thought my previous installation was causing issues, so I did a 'Search Local C:' in file explorer and found over 9,000 files involving PostgreSQL. I 'Ctrl+A' deleted all of them and skipped the exceptions saying 'You need permission to delete this file', 'This file is in use', 'Unable to locate file', etc.

I then tried to reinstall PostgreSQL 11.2 via this link (same as second link):
https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

However, after saying yes to 'permission to make changes on this computer', I immediately get the error box "There has been an error. Error reading file C;/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/data/postgresql.conf", and I can no longer install PostgreSQL.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Since you already manually deleted some things, but not other things, I'm not sure I can help much. But I think you need to somehow manually remove *all* the old PostgreSQL stuff, including the c:\program files\postgresql directory tree, and you *probably* ought to install the PostgreSQL distributed by postgresql.org: https://www.postgresql.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Mike from the comments. Here is what I did:

1) I found all the old PostgreSQL stuff, including the program files directory tree, and deleted all of it using the uninstall function when I could.

2) Next, I reset my postgresql system environment variables and restarted my computer.

3) I deleted all top level directories for PostgreSQL and downloaded the PostgreSQL distributed by postgresql.org. I was finally able to install PostgreSQL again.

4) PGAdmin4 works, and if I use the command line type 'cmd.exe /c chcp 1252' and then type something like 'psql -U postgres postgres" and enter your password.